# Activecollab System Status old-versions Routing error

Tags: php, upgrade, activecollab

After the latest upgrade to 5.11.0 when visiting the System Status page I am getting a blank screen. When looking at the network activity I see a 404 error that appears to be causing this.

```
{"type":"RoutingError","message":"String \u0027system/versions/old-versions\u0027 does not match any of mapped routes","file":"/home/time/public_html/activecollab/5.11.0/angie/classes/router/Router.class.php","line":563,"trace":null,"previous":null,"request_string":"system/versions/old-versions"}
```

The frontend appears to be calling a bad URL: api/v1/system/versions/old-versions endpoint.

I'm not sure what is happening here. Can anyone provide insight into why this is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by corrupt entries in routing_cache table, the solution is to truncate it like so:

```
DELETE FROM routing_cache;
```

You should also delete everything from cache and compile folders of your AC installation, except for .htaccess files if you see them there.

Comment: Thank you, this was absolutely the problem.